# Proving $\gcd(N^a-1,N^b-1)=N^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have come by one solution only, but things were derived too quickly without me understanding how or why. How does knowing that $\gcd(a,b)$ is a factor and a and b, actually derive that $N^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ is a factor of $N^a-1$ and $N^b-1$? How is it derived? I tried using congruence but it wouldn't work, and I can't seem to divide things that have summation and subtraction in them, Let alone show $N^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ is the greatest. I could really use any help.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

Comment: Do you know the identity $(a,b)=(a,b-a)$? Called Euclid's algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: WLoG suppose that $a\le b$, then we have
$$
N^b-1=N^aN^{b-a}-1=(N^a-1+1)N^{b-a}-1=(N^a-1)N^{b-a}+N^{b-a}-1
$$
Now use Euclid's algorithm to find that
$$
(N^a-1,N^b-1)=(N^a-1,N^{b-a}-1)
$$